# How to Return Fields of Models in Mongoid Using Rails and JSON

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have this sample document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f98fd1df2699a2f8a000003"),
    "comments" : "Foo bar",
    "location" : "Somewhere",
    "user_id" : ObjectId("4f98fd1df2699a2f8a000001")
}
```

When I retrieved the data using controller:

```
respond_to :json

def index
  respond_with Comment.all
end
```

It returns JSON:

```
[{
   "_id": "4f98fd1df2699a2f8a000003",
    "comments": "Foo bar",
    "location": "Somewhere",
    "user_id": "4f98fd1df2699a2f8a000001",
}]
```

My question is how can I include the fields of User class on the response easily?

```
class User
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :username
    field :first_name
    field :last_name
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the defaults of `as_json`.

```
def index
  respond_with Comment.all.as_json(:include => "user")
end
```

A better alternative would be to use a JSON template builder, such as [Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder).

Answer (score 0):

Try it with:

```
respond_with Comment.includes(:user).all
```

[See the doc here.](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#includes)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Still getting the same JSON response. I tried to include identity_map_enabled: true to mongoid.yml and restart the server. No luck. Do I need to add something to the model classes?